# Confused about ThreadLocal

Tags: java, thread-local

I just learned about ThreadLocal this morning.  I read that it should always be final and static like:

```
private static final ThreadLocal<Session> threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<Session>();
```

(Session is a Hibernate Session)

My confusion is this:  Because it is static, it is available to any thread in the JVM.  Yet it will hold information local to each thread which accesses it?  I'm trying to wrap my head around this so I apologize if this is unclear.  Each thread in the application has access to the same ThreadLocal object, but the ThreadLocal object will store objects local to each thread?

Comment: Beware of using this in web applications deployed in a shared environment. The thread local will leak across all contexts and after undeploying it references in the thread local will not be garbage collected. You need to remove the data after each request manually.

Comment: It's seemingly contradictory. `ThreadLocal` is supposed to be unique in each thread, but static objects are shared among each thread. Was just about to ask this same question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the instance would be the same, but the code attaches the value you set with the `Thread.currentThread()`, when you set and when you retrieve, so the value set will be accessible just within the current thread when accessed using the methods `set` and `get`.

Its really easy to understand it.

Imagine that each `Thread` has a map that associates a value to a `ThreadLocal` instance. Every time you perform a get or a set on a `ThreadLocal`, the implemention of `ThreadLocal` gets the map associated to the current `Thread` (`Thread.currentThread()`) and perform the `get` or `set` in that map using itself as key.

**Example:**

```
ThreadLocal tl = new ThreadLocal();
tl.set(new Object()); // in this moment the implementation will do something similar to Thread.getCurrentThread().threadLocals.put(tl, [object you gave]) 

Object obj = t1.get(); // in this moment the implementation will do something similar to Thread.getCurrentThread().threadLocals.get(tl)
```

And the interesting thing on this is that the `ThreadLocal` is hierarchic, meaning if you defined a value for a parent `Thread` it will be accessible from a child one.

Comment: You say imagine there's a map in the `ThreadLocal`. I get the concept. The thread id is the key, the unique instances are the values. So the overall `ThreadLocal` object is static, and holds one value per thread. Is it actually implemented with an internal map?

Comment: I just looked in the source code. It has an internal map. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/ThreadLocal.java#132

Answer (score 2):

You always access the same instance of ThreadLocal for a specific problem but this instance returns a different value for each thread calling the [get](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html#get%28%29) method.

That's the point : it's easy to find the object but each thread will have its specific own value. Thus you can for example make sure your specific value won't be accessed by two different threads.

You could see it (conceptually) as a kind of `HashMap<Thread><V>` which would always be accessed with `Thread.currentThread()` as key.

Answer (score 2):

Because the thread-specific values are not stored in the `ThreadLocal` object, but the [current Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#currentThread%28%29)'s `ThreadLocalMap`. The `ThreadLocal` object merely serves as key in these maps.

For details, read the JavaDoc of `ThreadLocal` and subclasses, or, if you are curious about the implementation, the source code available in every recent JDKs src.zip.